# What actions do you need to stitch together to get a blob into an Azure Files path (File Copy or File Create action)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

Using logic apps and event grid, I have no problem triggering event and getting blob properties, but how do I feed this into an Azure file server?
I can see the blob object, the url and so on. I can use Compose action to get the URL. When I pass the URL into a Copy File action of the Azure File object, it gives me a 404 that the file doesn't exist (hence the http 404 response code). Do I need to getBlobContent into a variable and write that to a file? Do I need to use the create SAS URI from the blob path and then use the SAS URI? The latter is what you'd do if you were sending a "click here to get blob" file link to a colleague. But my thought is that the Blob object exists as an accessible object when the trigger occurs (event grid see a file created in the stroage account). Documentation is not helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, you need to get the blob content first, then use "Create file" action to create it in your file server. Please refer to my logic app below:

[image]

In my logic app, I get the blob content with the path of the blob. Since you mentioned yo have got the url of the blob, so think you can substring the url and get the path. And then put the path into the "Blob" box of the "Get blob content" action.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues and found the 404 was regarding the formatting of the dynamic path returned from the blob.

I ended up (after a lot of hair pulling) stripping out the path using Compose and a bit of hard coded text in a "Get blob content using path" action.

Essentially (this is for my use case which was pulling json files out of blob into a LA workspace, but parts may be applicable for yourself)

**Get Subject (from the Eventgrid blob trigger action)**

**Compose**

- Inputs - (Subject)

**Get Blob content using path**

- Blob path - /directory/substring(...)
- Infer Content Type - NO

(The Substring expression here I am using is - **substring(outputs('Compose'), x)** where x is the number of characters before my hardcoded directory in the path.

Then -

**Initialize variable**

- Name - BlobContentAsText
- Type - String
- Value - File Content (from Get blob content using path)

Then -

**Send Data (Preview)**

- JSON Request Body - BlobContentAsText
- Custom Log Name - Logs_CL